# Only allowing portrait view on app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, portrait

I am trying to make an app that is only viewable in portrait. Im looking for a way to deactivate landscape modes all together. So far my search hasn't yielded a functional answer.

I was hoping someone could send me in the right direction. I am open for any method to accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 2):

Just deselect the two landscape modes in the target's Deployment Info (under the General tab):

[image: Portrait only settings]

Comment: Additional note as a user of iOS apps: please support "upside down" in addition to "portrait"; it is very handy if you need to prop the device up on some kind of stand but want the data cable attached.

Comment: for some reason the 'upside down' doesn't seem to do anything. when i run my simulator the display is upside down when i think it should be right side up if that makes any sense.

Comment: @F.Skehan It might be an iPad-only feature currently (not sure about iPhone 6 Plus) but just leave it checked in case future models take advantage of it. =)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project settings and find Deployment Info section. This is where you set the orientations that you want to support.